# New browser tab doesn't load styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a React application where I'm opening a new browser tab on click. The problem is that my styled component's style won't load in this new browser tab.

Why is my styled component's style not loading in the new browser tab?

This is my browser tab component:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

export const NewBrowserTab = ({ children }) => {
  const [container, setContainer] = useState(null)
  const newWindow = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setContainer(document.createElement('div'))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (container) {
      newWindow.current = window.open('', '')
      newWindow.current.document.body.appendChild(container)

      return () => {
        newWindow.current.close()
      }
    }
  }, [container])

  return container && createPortal(children, container)
}
```

And this is where I use that component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { NewBrowserTab } from '@components/NewBrowserTab/NewBrowserTab'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const DownloadButton = () => {

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>open window</button>
      {isActive &&
        <NewBrowserTab>
          <MyStyledComponent>this is supposed to be red in new window!</MyStyledComponent>
        </NewBrowserTab>}
    </>
  )
}

const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
`

export default DownloadButton
```

And here you can see the styling is not there in devtools (no red or blue color):

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Quentin, thank you for your help. I'll post this answer to answer my question in detail with code as well (if anyone will ever stumble upon this issue in the future):

The styled component won't load in the new tab when I use direct DOM manipulation in the "NewBrowserTab"-component.

So what I did instead was adding a new route with this page component:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import Flex from '@components/containers/Flex'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const DocumentPage: FC = () => {

  return (
    <Flex direction='column'>
      <MyStyledComponent>123</MyStyledComponent>
    </Flex>
  )
}

const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
`

export default DocumentPage
```

and opening it in a new tab with the React Router:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const DownloadButton = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Link to="dokument" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        new tab with styled component
      </Link>
    </>
  )
}

export default DownloadButton
```

This means I can get rid of the NewBrowserTab-component AND wherever I navigate in my app, the window will still be open since it no longer is a component that can unmount!

Answer (score 1):

Styled components work by generating a `<style>` element which contains some rule-sets which are applied to elements generated from components via class names.

You are copying the element with the class names to the new window, but not the `<style>` element.

---

Generally, I'd approach this problem using a React Router and pointing the new window at a URL which passes data describing what you want to display through that.

Comment: how do I copy the <style> element? I don't understand

Comment: I wouldn't. It's too fiddly and anti-React.

Comment: then how would you do instead?

Comment: (gestures at the last paragraph of the answer)

Comment: I'm trying to apply css, not pass data? I'm confused. You mean I would send the css-rules through the router, and then apply it to the element?

Comment: No, you'd load the React application in the new window instead of doing direct DOM manipulation. You'd use React Router to show only the component you'd want to show. Then, since you'd have a React application in the new window (and not a single element you copied to it) then Styled Components would work.

Comment: ok I think I understand, I'll use the react router instead and see where I end up, I'll update later with what I find

thank you :)

Comment: Opening a new tab with the React Router was a lot easier! I can't believe all my previous  google searches led me to people recommending to open the new tab with DOM manipulation in a separate component, it's awful in comparison. I'll edit my post with the easy solution :)

Thank you so much for your help!